# Numerically Representing Mathematica's Root Object in Open-Source Language

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wolfram-mathematica, solver

### Question

I would like to reproduce a `Root[]` object, *ideally* in a `python` function.

Is there any particular library that would be suited for this process?

### Attempts

If I understand the `Root[]` function properly, it is simply finding the nth degree root of a polynomial and so I and taking a stab that [`numpy.roots`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) would suffice by taking `#1` as the argument `x` in the `numpy` docs.

### Background

I have a number of 5th order polynomial root which cannot be reduced with `ToRadicals` due to the order that were obtained from a particularly nasty Inverse Laplace Transform.

### Minimal Mathematica example

```
r = 1/τ;
ct = Cos[θ];
r2 = r^2;
r3 = r^3;
r4 = r2^2;
ct2 = ct^2;
ct3 = ct^3;
ct4 = ct2^2;
ct5 = ct^5;
ct6 = ct2^3;
p2 = ϕ^2;

fn := Root[2*ρ*p2*r^5 + 2*ρ*p2*r^5*ct - 2*ρ^2*p2*r^5*ct - 2*ρ*p2*r^5*ct2 - 2*ρ*p2*r^5*ct3 + 2*ρ^2*p2*r^5*ct3 + (r4 + 4*p2*r4 + 4*ρ*p2*r4 + r4*ct - 2*ρ*r4*ct + 4*p2*r4*ct - 2*ρ*p2*r4*ct - 2*ρ^2*p2*r4*ct - r4*ct2 - 4*p2*r4*ct2 - r4*ct3 + 2*ρ*r4*ct3 - 4*p2*r4*ct3 + 6*ρ*p2*r4*ct3 -  2*ρ^2*p2*r4*ct3)*#1 + (4*r3 + 8*p2*r3 + 2*ρ*p2*r3 +  3*r3*ct - 6*ρ*r3*ct + 4*p2*r3*ct - 4*ρ*p2*r3*ct - 3*r3*ct2 - 4*p2*r3*ct2 + 2*ρ*p2*r3*ct2 - 2*r3*ct3 + 4*ρ*r3*ct3)*#1^2 + (6*r2 + 4*p2*r2 + 3*r2*ct -  6*ρ*r2*ct - 3*r2*ct2 - r2*ct3 +  2*ρ*r2*ct3)*#1^3 + (4*r + r*ct - 2*ρ*r*ct -  r*ct2)*#1^4 + #1^5 &, 5]
```

Comment: I would point out that if any really good non-python solutions exist then feel free to offer them!

Comment: strictly speaking `Root` does not "find" roots, it is more of a container holding your expression.  You need to operate on your `Root` object with `N` to extract approximate numerical values.  If you restrict yourself to polynomials with numerical coefficients a `Root` object would look pretty much like just a list of coefficients in python and a specifier for which root,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in symbolic calculations, you can use [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html).  In particular, SymPy has polynomial objects and the classes `RootOf` and `CRootOf` to represent the roots of polynomials.

For example,

```
In [103]: from sympy import Symbol, poly

In [104]: x = Symbol('x')

In [105]: p = poly(x**4 - 3*x**2 + x - 1)

In [106]: p
Out[106]: Poly(x**4 - 3*x**2 + x - 1, x, domain='ZZ')

In [107]: p.root(0)
Out[107]: CRootOf(x**4 - 3*x**2 + x - 1, 0)
```

`CRootOf(poly, k)` is a placeholder for the kth root of the polynomial.  To find its numerical value, use the `.evalf()` method:

```
In [109]: p.root(0).evalf()
Out[109]: -1.94397243715073
```

Here are the numerical values of all the roots:

```
In [110]: [p.root(k).evalf() for k in range(p.degree())]
Out[110]: 
[-1.94397243715073,
 1.66143946800762,
 0.141266484571554 - 0.538201812325831*I,
 0.141266484571554 + 0.538201812325831*I]
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I just tested vs. the function above and it reproduced the same results

Comment: `from sympy import Symbol` not `symbol` by the way.

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that.  Both `symbol` and `Symbol` can be imported, and  I had imported `Symbol` earlier in this ipython session.

Comment: I spent some time investigating this as `sympy` is a bit overkill considering my problem. it turns out that `numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots` does the same job. `sympy` has a `mathematica` conversion tool which can be used to get the form correct straight from `mathematica` and then can be converted into a `Poly(, x)` object with sympy. The coefficients can be extracted with `c = p.coeffs()` and `c.reverse()` must be used to get into `numpy` format. Finally you can hardcode `c` and call `polyroots(c)` in a python function call